# Polygon in readWKT("POLYGON ((.))") function in rgeos package

Tags: r, polygon, geospatial

Let us consider a 2-d polygon  (X) with sufficiently large number of (say 20) vertices:

```
x= c(0.0003969323 , 0.008053435,  0.01570994,  0.02336644,  0.02873640,
    0.024194693, 0.019652986, 0.01511128, 0.01056957, 0.006027866, 
   -0.0003964319, -0.008052642, -0.01570885, -0.02336506, -0.02874606 ,-0.024202093,  
   -0.019658130,-0.01511417, -0.01057020, -0.006026239,  0.0003969323)

y=c( -0.0280138365, -0.023670987, -0.01932814, -0.01498529, -0.01004309,
 -0.002502845, 0.005037398 ,0.01257764, 0.02011789, 0.027658129,    
  0.0280152119, 0.023671847,  0.01932848,  0.01498512,  0.01004582,
  0.002506936, -0.005031947,-0.01257083 ,-0.02010971, -0.027648598, -0.0280138365)

X=cbind(x,y)
```

I am trying to get the polygon using the following code and will compute the difference between the area of two such polygons:

```
C=cbind(X[1,],X[2,])
C1=toString(paste(C[,1], C[,2], collapse = ','))
C2=noquote(C1)
poly_1=readWKT("POLYGON ((C2))")
```

But it is giving error:

> ParseException: Expected number but encountered word: 'C2'.

Could any one please suggest how overcome this error.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik. Thanks for your suggestion. I did it.

Comment: `readWKT` isn't my strong suit, but by looking at the examples in the help file, your `C2` isn't formatted properly. It's expecting pairs of coordinates, separated by commas, with each edge in its own braces.

Answer (score 2):

This is my first time posting here, but I have got so many great solutions from StackOverflow that I would like to try to help as well.

Here is an example that works:

x and y are the points

```
x<-c(0,3,3,0,0)
y<-c(0,0,3,3,0)
```

Notice that last and first elements are the same!

polygon needs to end at the same place that it begins.

Now, create a string to be evaluated

```
ply<-paste0(noquote(
          paste(x,y,collapse=",")
          )
   )
ply<-paste0("POLYGON ((",ply,"))")
ply<-paste0('readWKT("',ply,'")')
```

Up to this point ply is a string with the special characther "

```
\ #[1] "readWKT(\"POLYGON ((0 0,3 0,3 3,0 3,0 0))\")"
```

Finally, evaluate the expression to create the polygon

```
ply<-eval(parse(text=ply))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will catch you with my say soon.